# Detectar Colisao e Reagir game lua

Tags: lua

Eu queria ajuda com colisao 2d em quadrados e como evitar que o personagem passe pelo bloco
Segue o codigo do player:

```
   local player = nil
Player = {}
player_skins = {
    human  = love.graphics.newImage("skin.png")
}

function Player:create()
player = {
    x = 1000,
    y = 1500,
    angle  = 0,
    speed = 1,
    xveloc = 0,
    yveloc = 0,
    maxveloc = 4
    }
end

function Player:movement(dt)
    if player.yveloc > 0 and player.yveloc > 0.1 then
        player.yveloc = player.yveloc - 10*dt
    elseif player.yveloc < 0 and player.yveloc < -0.1 then
        player.yveloc = player.yveloc + 10*dt
    elseif player.yveloc < 0.1 and  player.yveloc > 0 then
        player.yveloc = 0
    elseif player.yveloc < 0 and player.yveloc > -0.1 then
        player.yveloc = 0
    end
    if player.xveloc > 0 and player.xveloc > 0.1 then
        player.xveloc = player.xveloc - 10*dt
    elseif player.xveloc < 0 and player.xveloc < -0.1 then
        player.xveloc = player.xveloc + 10*dt
    elseif player.yveloc < 0.1 and  player.xveloc > 0 then
        player.xveloc = 0
    elseif player.yveloc < 0 and player.xveloc > -0.1 then
        player.xveloc = 0
    end
    if player ~= nil and not pause then
        player.x = player.x + player.xveloc
        player.y = player.y + player.yveloc 
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("w") then
        if player.yveloc  <= player.maxveloc and player.yveloc > (player.maxveloc - (player.maxveloc*2)) then
            player.yveloc = player.yveloc - (player.speed*dt*20)
        end
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("s") then
        if player.yveloc  < player.maxveloc and player.yveloc > (player.maxveloc - (player.maxveloc*2)) then
            player.yveloc = player.yveloc + (player.speed*dt*20)
        end
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("d") then
        if player.xveloc  < player.maxveloc and player.xveloc > (player.maxveloc - (player.maxveloc*2)) then
            player.xveloc = player.xveloc + (player.speed*dt*20)
        end
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("a") then
        if player.xveloc  < player.maxveloc and player.xveloc >         (player.maxveloc - (player.maxveloc*2)) then
            player.xveloc = player.xveloc - (player.speed*dt*50)
        end
    end
end

function Player:camera(dt)
    camera.x  = player.x - love.graphics.getWidth()/2
    camera.y = player.y- love.graphics.getHeight()/2
end

function Player:AngleRelatedToMouse()
    player.angle = math.atan2(love.mouse.getY() -     love.graphics.getHeight()/2,love.mouse.getX() - love.graphics.getWidth()/2) -         1.5
end

function Player:draw()
    love.graphics.draw(player_skins.human,player.x,player.y,player.angle,0.2,    0.2,player_skins.human:getWidth()/2,player_skins.human:getHeight()/2)
end

function Player:checkcollid()
    a = require ""

end

function Player:get()

return player
end
```

Tambem . o mapa que fiz em tiled . todos as camadas tem a propriedade solid
com 1 ou 0 (vou colocar 2 no futuro pra portas e outros) ele coloca todos que tem solid 1 em uma tabela chamada wall

o codigo que eu fiz pegava todos os elementos presente na tabela wall e  checava os 4 lados pra ver se o player estava encostando no bloco especifico
eu n posso disponibilizar esta parte do codigo pois eu apaguei ontem d noite e.e ... .

o problema é que quando eu checo se o player está encostando no bloco ele zera a velocidade x e y nao deixando o player ir para traz . mas continua entrando no bloco

procurei todos os tipos só achei os metodo de aabb e o raycast 
que nao consegui fazer para evitar que o player entre no bloco
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

n sou mt bom em ingles e tem umas funcoes que nao tem nenhum significado real

Comment: @bigown A pergunta duplicata foi removida?

Comment: @Phanpy foi sim, você quer responder essa?

Comment: @bigown Estava pensando se eu iria... hm, acho que vou esperar uma próxima pergunta, está precisando de um edit ainda :/